# Enterprise Library 5: Creating instances of Enterprise Library objects

Tags: winforms, enterprise-library-5

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0 in my win-form Application.

**1. Regarding creating instances of Enterprise Library objects**

What is the best way to Resolve the reference for Logging / exception objects? In our application, we have different applications in solution. So Solutions have below project:

CommonLib (Class Lib)
CustomerApp (winform app)
CustWinService (win service proj)
ClassLib2 (class Lib)

I have implemented logging / exceptions as below in CommonLib project. Created a class AppLog as below:

```
 public class AppLog
    {
        public static LogWriter defaultWriter = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>();
public static ExceptionManager exManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
        public AppLog()
        {
        }

    public static void WriteLog(string LogMessage, string LogCategories)
    {
        // Create a LogEntry and populate the individual properties.
            if (defaultWriter.IsLoggingEnabled())
            {
                string[] Logcat = LogCategories.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                LogEntry entry2 = new LogEntry();
                entry2.Categories = Logcat;
                entry2.EventId = 9007;
                entry2.Message = LogMessage;
                entry2.Priority = 9;
                entry2.Title = "Logging Block Examples";
                defaultWriter.Write(entry2);
            }
    }
}
```

And then I used Applog class as below for logging and exception in different projects:

```
            try
            {
                AppLog.WriteLog("This is Production Log Entry.", "ExceCategory");
                string strtest = string.Empty;
                strtest = strtest.Substring(1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                bool rethrow = AppLog.exManager.HandleException(ex, "ExcePolicy");

            }
```

So its the correct way to use Logging and Exception? or any other way i can improve it?

**2. Logging File Name dynamic**

In logging block, we have fileName which need to be set in app.config file. Is there a way I can assign fileName value dynamically through coding? Since I don't want to hard code it in config file and paths are different for production and development environment.

Thanks
TShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your application loosely coupled and easier to test, I would recommend defining separate logging and exception handling interfaces, then having your `AppLog` class implement both. Your application can then perform logging and exception handling via those interfaces, with `AppLog` providing the implementation.

You can have a different file name set per environment using config transforms, which I believe you can use in a winforms application by using [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/view/Discussions/9).